# In 1 Corinthians 14, What Is The Understanding of the Word 'Sign'?

Tags: 1-corinthians, prophecy, sign

Specifically, verse 22 of 1 Corinthians 14 states,

> "Speaking in tongues, then, is intended as a **sign**, not for believers but for unbelievers, while prophecy is not for unbelievers but for believers."

In context how is the word '**sign**' used? In the previous verses, explanation of clarity is made by Paul, and the very next verse (23) states,

> "If, therefore, the whole church assembles together and all are speaking in tongues and people who are outsiders or unbelievers come in, will they not say that you are out of your minds?"

This verse 23 sounds like tongues show an aversion to sanity to the unbeliever. Previous verses show tongues as needing clarity for the hearers to understand. How is any of this a 'sign'?

Again, if we look back at verse 22, how is prophecy a 'sign' to believers and tongues a 'sign' for unbelievers, unless we take the word 'sign' to mean a guidepost to direct someone in a certain direction? Or should we take the word 'sign' as meaning a miracle of sorts?

Comment: The Greek word translated 'sign' is about something that points to that which it signifies, It is not the thing to be dwelt on - it is a pointer, and the person seeing the sign needs to look beyond the sign to that which it points. We get our word 'semaphore' from it. That is why it's wrong to dwell on tongue-speaking as many do today, as if the sign was proof about something to do with the person using the sign. No, it must spell out the gospel of Christ and all attention be drawn to him!

Comment: Thanks @Anne. I believe a sign is like you said - something that points to something. This is why I accepted the answer from Dave below.

Comment: Ten hours after commenting that you've accepted Dave's answer, it still has not been 'ticked' as the one acceptable to you. I mention this just in case you thought you had accepted it but your 'tick' had not registered.

Comment: You were right, @Anne. Just ticked the checkmark. New to this, so thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Speaking in tongues is a sign to unbelievers, not believers. Usually a sign is a positive thing that helps people believe (Luke 2:12), but there are also negative signs that are intended to be stumbling blocks to those with hardened hearts (Mark 6:52, Mark 8:17).

Simeon prophesied over Jesus at His circumcision in the temple that Jesus would be a sign that would be spoken against (Luke 2:34). Isaiah also prophesied that the Messiah would be “a stone of stumbling,” “a rock of offence,” “a gin,” and “a snare” (Isaiah 8:14). These prophecies certainly came true in many people’s lives. Isaiah also said, in the scriptures that Paul had just quoted (Isaiah 28:11-12), that despite this miraculous manifestation, “they would not hear.”

Therefore, speaking in tongues is a negative sign to unbelievers that will cause them to think we are crazy (1 Corinthians 14:23). That’s the point Paul was making, and that is the reason he was telling them not to speak in tongues in church in a way that dominates the assembly (1 Corinthians 14:28).

Someone might say, “But the disciples spoke in tongues on the Day of Pentecost, and 3,000 people were saved” (Acts 2:41). However, those tongues were the known languages of the people who were listening. Tongues with an interpretation equals prophecy (1 Corinthians 14:5). Since those tongues were able to be interpreted by the hearers, that had the same positive effect that prophecy has (1 Corinthians 14:24-25).

So, Paul quoted Old Testament scripture to verify that tongues are a negative sign that will cause unbelievers to reject our witness. This was done to persuade the Corinthians not to speak in tongues in church without an interpretation.

In verse 23 Paul was stating that if all are speaking in unknown tongues in the church service and people come in who are either unlearned or unbelievers, they will conclude that these people are insane and suffer from a disorder of the mind.

The Greek word for “unlearned” in this passage is “IDIOTES,” from which we derive the English word “idiot.” It is simply denoting someone who is ignorant of this gift of speaking in tongues, and was translated “ignorant” in Acts 4:

The Greek word that was translated “unbelievers” here is “APISTOS.” This is a compound word consisting of “PISTOS” and “A.” PISTOS is the adjective form of “PISTIS,” the Greek word for faith, and A is being used here as a negative particle (Strong’s Concordance). Therefore, this is describing someone who is against speaking in tongues or doesn’t believe in it.

This verse is simply saying that tongues has a negative effect on unbelievers, while prophecy has a positive effect on those who will believe.

Comment: I think this makes really good sense and believe this is the correct interpretation. I've heard this before and your explanation makes it easier to grasp. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The operative word in 1 Cor 14:22 is σημεῖον (sémeion) = sign, portent, miracle.

BDAG gives two basic meanings for this word:

> 1. **a sign of distinguishing mark whereby something is known, *sign, token, indication***, eg, Luke 2:12, 2 Thess 3:17, Matt 26:48, Mark
>    13:4, Luke 21:7, Matt 24:3, 16:3, 1 Cor 14:22, Luke 11:29, 30, 2:34,
>    etc
> 2. **an event that is an indication or confirmation of intervention by transcendent powers, *miracle, portent***, eg, Matt 12:38, 16:1, Mark
>    8:11, 12, etc.

Note what 1 Cor 14:22 is saying in context:

> **18** I thank God that I speak in tongues more than all of you. **19** But in the church, I would rather speak five coherent words to instruct others than ten thousand words in a tongue.
>
> **20** Brothers, stop thinking like children. In regard to evil be infants, but in your thinking be mature. **21** It is written in the
> Law: “By strange tongues and foreign lips I will speak to this people,
> but even then they will not listen to Me, says the Lord.”
>
> **22 Tongues, then, are a sign, not for believers, but for unbelievers. Prophecy, however, is for believers, not for
> unbelievers.**
>
> **23** So if the whole church comes together and everyone speaks in tongues, and some who are uninstructed or some unbelievers come in,
> will they not say that you are out of your minds? **24** But if an
> unbeliever or uninstructed person comes in while everyone is
> prophesying, he will be convicted and called to account by all, **25**
> and the secrets of his heart will be made known. So he will fall
> facedown and worship God, proclaiming, “God is truly among you!”

Paul is distinguishing between two spiritual gifts - prophecy vs tongues.  He has previously said that the gift of prophecy is greater and more important than others (1 Cor 12:28).  In 1 Cor 14 Paul now expands on that point to show when & how these gifts should be used:

- **Prophecy** is to be used among believers to preach and expound the word
- **Tongues** are used to reach unbelievers, not believers.  That is, the gift of tongues is used to reach those who speak another language in  strange lands/places so they can understand the gospel as was done in Acts 2 at Pentecost.

Paul's point is clear - if an unbeliever walks into a Christian meeting and hears the Word prophesied, he/she will be impressed.  However, if the same unbeliever walks in a hears a cacophony of strange tongues, he/she will think people are out of their minds.

Comment: I can see this, though the encouragement is to have a clear understanding to both unbeliever and believer. This did happen in Acts 2, as you mentioned, by a timed miracle of God so others could hear these visitors from other countries praising God in their own languages. I'm not 100% certain there is proof of this as a means of communication for the rest of the book Acts, is there?

Comment: @RobCallicotte - must theology be based only on the book of Acts?

Comment: Thanks @Dottard. No. That was the only example I've seen in the New Testament, which is why I mentioned it. God did do as you mentioned then. When other time did God use the gift of tongues to speak to others from people who did not speak their audience's native tongue?

Comment: @RobCallicotte - the miracle of tongues as recorded in Acts 2 appears to be on both the preacher and the listener because of the subtle distinction made between tongues and dialects in the Greek.  I agree this is the only concrete example of the gift of tongues anywhere in the NT.  However, Paul alludes to it in a few other places.

Comment: @RobCallicotte - By the same token - very few of the spiritual gifts listed in 1 Cor 12, Rom 12, etc, have concrete, explicit exemplars in the NT.

Comment: Yes, @Dottard. I have seen that, which calls into order these specific gifts' place of value by lack of real examples, and therefore an intimation (only) of these particular gifts' order of priority. Being lesser by example could be a nuanced way the Holy Spirit helped us to see other things are more important than these stated gifts in 1 Corinthians 14. Even more concretely, Paul said tongues was a lesser gift and had no value if the listener could gain no opportunity to understand. Thanks again for the dialogue. In light of 1 Corinthians 13, the true goal is love for the listener.